# How can I find the DOOM level?

Tags: rage, doom

I have heard that there is also a secret level as a homage to id Software's game Doom, in their game RAGE.

Where can I find this level and what do I need to do in order to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the Doom level, you will need to travel to Gearhead Vault, within Subway Town. Once you're able to access this level;

- Kill all enemies and head towards the area near the end with the computers
- Activate seven of these computers (use video for reference as to which) - you will hear a sound from DOOM for every computer you interact with
- Once activated all computers are activated you will hear a second sound effect from DOOM
- Head back to the start of the level
- A previously locked door will now be unlocked
- "Use" the teleporter to transport to E1M1

Here is a youtube video detailing how to find this hidden room:

Finding this secret level will also allow you to find the Doom Marine bobblehead item:

[image]